# can a select box, open another window or modal box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have code like so:

```
<div class="field4"><label for="go" >Info <a href="helper/info.html?lightbox[width]=560&lightbox[height]=600" class="lightbox"><span class="helper open">?</span></a></label>

                            <select id="go" name="go">
                                <option value="">Please select an option</option>
                                <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                                <option value="no">No</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
```

If they select YES , I would like to invoke a href to specific address,perhaps a modal box
Is this dooable ?

Have checked around and not seen how to do it.

Ok the update is:

```
<div class="field4">
                            <img src="images/bugme.png" class="bugmeFloat"><label for="sms" >SMS Alerts <a href="helper/sms.html?lightbox[width]=560&lightbox[height]=600" class="lightbox"><span class="helper open">?</span></a></label>

                            <select id="sms" name="sms">
                                <option value="">Please select an option</option>
                                <option value="no">No thanks</option>
                                <option value="yes">Purchase SMS Messaging</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <!--inline script for modal open off select choice-->
                        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
                        $(function() {
                            $('#sms').change(function() {
                                 if ($(this).val() == 'yes') {
                                     window.location = 'helper/sms.html?lightbox[width]=560&lightbox[height]=600';
                                 }
                            });
                        });
                        </script>

                        <!--//end inline modal box open -->
```

It isnt opening window or modal..... hmm

Comment: Not to be picky (and I realise this may be simplified for demonstration purposes), but isn't clicking on a link both *easier* and, essentially, a binary decision for the user anyway? (They either click (effectively a 'yes'), or don't click (effectively a 'no').)

Comment: Its not being picky. We have a large form, for clients updating their profiles. One element of which is to order a specific item, by using this method, we can control everything on one page. Without them leaving the form. Well essentially, my desire is to open a modal box which we can then invoke payment. Which then returns them to the form. At which point we will probaly disable that form element upon success and date time it, so it cannot be used again for a set period of time. Its my logic lol

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You would have something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#go').change(function() {
         if ($(this).val() == 'yes') {
             window.location = 'www.mynewaddress.com';
         }
    });
});
```

Essentially, you are navigating to a new address when they change the select's value, if a certain condition is met.

Relevant documentation:

- jQuery's `.change()` event - http://api.jquery.com/change/
- JavaScript redirect - http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptredirect.php

Comment: Can anyone else come up with a "working" version for this, as I have tested many versions and cannot seem to get it to play ball.

Comment: Nearest I have got to this is, onchange events. http://lab.artlung.com/dropdown/ But this is flawed too... I just cannot get the scripts pasted above to work